# Find item in specific listview column and selects it

Tags: c#, visual-studio, listview

I used this code to find and select:

```
ListViewItems find = listview.FindItemWithText(txtFind.Text);
if(find != null)
{
    listview.TopItem = find;
    find.Selected = true;
}
else
{
}
```

The problem is it searches the entire column, I need to only search the 2nd column.

Answer (score 0):

Search the text in the desired column like this:

```
ListViewItems find = listview.Columns[1].ListView.FindItemWithText(txtFind.Text)
```

Comment: Sorry but it doesnt work. And the unmodified code seems to only search the first 2 columns and It has 4